# How to make all of these values positive?

Tags: java, arrays, null

I need to change the body to make all of these values positive but I am not sure what `@param arr != null` means or how to use it. I am also not sure exactly how arrays work and how the null values work and it is very confusing for me. I also do not understand why whenever I tried to change some of the code it would always give me syntax errors.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArraysPractice
{
  /**
 * Do not change any values in the main method below.
*/
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
int[] array1 = {2, 42, 1};
int[] array2 = {4, -1, -3, 0, 8, -4, 2};
int[] array3 = {-8, 42, 1, 42, -1, 1, -2, 42, -5, 0, 2, 42};
System.out.println("sumUpValuesInArray test:");
System.out.println(sumUpValuesInArray(array1) == 45 ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected 45 but you returned " + sumUpValuesInArray(array1));
System.out.println(sumUpValuesInArray(array2) == 6 ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected 6 but you returned " + sumUpValuesInArray(array2));
System.out.println(sumUpValuesInArray(array3) == 156 ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected 156 but you returned " + sumUpValuesInArray(array3));

System.out.println("\ncount42's test:");
System.out.println(count42s(array1) == 1 ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected 1 but you returned " + count42s(array1));
System.out.println(count42s(array2) == 0 ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected 0 but you returned " + count42s(array2));
System.out.println(count42s(array3) == 4 ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected 4 but you returned " + count42s(array3));

System.out.println("\nfindFirstLocation test");
System.out.println(findFirstLocation(array1, 42) == 1 ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected 1 but you returned " + findFirstLocation(array1, 42));
System.out.println(findFirstLocation(array1, 44) == -1 ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected -1 but you returned " + findFirstLocation(array1, 44));
System.out.println(findFirstLocation(array2, 8) == 4 ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected 4 but you returned " + findFirstLocation(array1, 8));
System.out.println(findFirstLocation(array2, 18) == -1 ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected -1 but you returned " + findFirstLocation(array1, 18));
System.out.println(findFirstLocation(array3, 42) == 1 ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected 1 but you returned " + findFirstLocation(array1, 42));

System.out.println("\nmakeThemAllPostive test:");
makeThemAllPostive(array1);
String actual = Arrays.toString(array1);
System.out.println(actual.equals("[2, 42, 1]") ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected [2, 42, 1] but you returned " + actual);
makeThemAllPostive(array2);
actual = Arrays.toString(array2);
System.out.println(actual.equals("[4, 1, 3, 0, 8, 4, 2]") ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected [4, 1, 3, 0, 8, 4, 2] but you returned " + actual);
makeThemAllPostive(array3);
actual = Arrays.toString(array3);
System.out.println(
  actual.equals("[8, 42, 1, 42, 1, 1, 2, 42, 5, 0, 2, 42]") ? "Passed!"
    : "Expected [8, 42, 1, 42, 1, 1, 2, 42, 5, 0, 2, 42] but you returned "
      + actual);
}

 /**
  * Given a non-null array, return the sum of all elements.
  * 
  * @param arr
 *          != null
* @return sum of all elements
*/
public static int sumUpValuesInArray(int[] arr)
{
 // TODO: Complete the body of this method so that all of the tests say
  // Passed! in the console.
  return 42;

  // Integer array1 = null;
  // return Integer int[] array4;

 }

  /**
 * Given a non-null array, count the number of elements that are 42.
 * 
* @param theArray
 *          != null
 * @return number of elements that are 42.
 */
public static int count42s(int[] theArray)
   {
    // TODO: Complete the body of this method so that all of the tests 
 say
    // Passed! in the console.
    return 42;
  }

/**
 * Given a non-null array, return the index of the first location of 
value
 * found from the beginning of the array. If the item is not in the 
array,
 * return -1.
 * 
 * @param arr
 *          != null
* @param value
 *          may or may not be in the array.
 * @return
 */
public static int findFirstLocation(int[] arr, int value)
     {
      // TODO: Complete the body of this method so that all of the tests 
say
    // Passed! in the console.
  return 42;
}

/**
 * Removes the negative signs from all values in the array. This 
mutates the
   * original array and changes the values in it.
 * 
 * @param arr
 *          !=null
 */
public static void makeThemAllPostive(int[] arr)
{
    // TODO: Complete the body of this method so that all of the tests 
say
    // Passed! in the console.
   int[] array2 * != null;



 //   int[] array2 = new int[] {4, 1, 3, 0, 8, 4, 2};
   // int[] array3 = new int[] {8, 42, 1, 42, 1, 1, 2, 42, 5, 0, 2, 42};

}

}
```

Comment: For better, sooner help post [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The `@param arr != null` that you see in

```
/**
 * Removes the negative signs from all values in the array. This mutates the
 * original array and changes the values in it.
 * 
 * @param arr
 *          !=null
 */
```

is actually part of a [JavaDoc](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html) comment (see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc))

The `@param` tag describes a parameter (the next word, `arr` in your case) and the remainder of the description (`!= null`) is just what the author of the JavaDoc comment added as description for the parameter.

This description seems to be hint from the author that your code should not expect `null` as a valid argument for that parameter and may do anything it pleases if it is still passed a `null` value instead of an array.